# Why does server-side DataTables not return any data?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, datatables

I am trying to adapt Ryan Bates RailsCast on [DataTables](http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables) to my project, but using server side processing. The headers display fine when I call the index view, but the table body says 'No data available in table'; yet I have >10K records. My project differs from the example by the main object being display is Genotypes, with two related tables. 
Here is my (the initial part of) class GenotypesDatables (analogous to ProductsDatables in the example):

```
class GenotypesDatatable
  delegate :params, :h, :link_to, to: :@view

  def initialize(view)
    @view = view
  end

  def as_json(options = {})
    # This is what feeds directly into DataTables
    {
      sEcho: params[:sEcho].to_i,
      iTotalRecords: Genotype.count,
      iTotalDisplayRecords: 20,
      aaData: data
    }
  end

private

  def data
    genotypes.map do |genotype|
      [
        # Note: h is shorthand for html_escape
        # Am unsure is this is correct way to call records; compare
        # to 340-datatables example.
        h(genotype.gmarker.marker),
        h(genotype.gsample.labid),
        h(genotype.gsample.subjectid),
        h(genotype.gsample.box),
        h(genotype.gsample.well),
        h(genotype.allele1),
        h(genotype.allele2),
        h(genotype.run_date)
      ]
    end
  end
```

Here's the (relevant part of) the Genotypes controller:

```
class GenotypesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /genotypes
  # GET /genotypes.json
  def index
     respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: GenotypesDatatable.new(view_context) }
    end
  end
```

I cannot tell is this is enough code to diagnose the problem, but if anyone is familiar with this excellent gem (it is perfect for my project), and needs to see more code, please let me know. (I've been all over SO, but cannot find an answer..)
thanks!

[Added edit, based on comments]

Here is the full class for GenotypeDatatables:

```
class GenotypesDatatable
  delegate :params, :h, :link_to, to: :@view

  def initialize(view)
    @view = view
  end

  def as_json(options = {})
    # This is what feeds directly into DataTables
    {
      sEcho: params[:sEcho].to_i,
      iTotalRecords: Genotype.count,
      iTotalDisplayRecords: 20,
      aaData: data
    }
  end

private

  def data
    genotypes.map do |genotype|
      [
        # Note: h is shorthand for html_escape
        # Am unsure is this is correct way to call records; compare
        # to 340-datatables example.
        h(genotype.gmarker.marker),
        h(genotype.gsample.labid),
        h(genotype.gsample.subjectid),
        h(genotype.gsample.box),
        h(genotype.gsample.well),
        h(genotype.allele1),
        h(genotype.allele2),
        h(genotype.run_date)
      ]
    end
  end

  def genotypes
    @genotypes ||= fetch_genotypes
  end

  def fetch_genotypes
    genotypes = Genotype.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
    genotypes = genotypes.page(page).per_page(per_page)
    if params[:sSearch].present?
      genotypes = genotypes.where("labid like :search or category like :search", search: "%#{params[:sSearch]}%")
    end
  end

  def page
    params[:iDisplayStart].to_i/per_page + 1
  end

  def per_page
    params[:iDisplayLength].to_i > 0 ? params[:iDisplayLength].to_i : 10
  end

  def sort_column
    columns = %w[allele1 allele2 run_date]
    columns[params[:iSortCol_0].to_i]
  end

  def sort_direction
    params[:sSortDir_0] == "desc" ? "desc" : "asc"
  end
end
```

Here is the javascript file, in /app/assets/javascript/genotypes.js.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
    $('#genotypes').dataTable
    bJQueryUI: true
    bProcessing: true
    bServerSide: true
    bDeferRender: true
    "sAjaxSource": $('#genotypes').data('source')
```

And here is the view in which I'm attempting to render my Datatables:

```
<h1>Listing genotypes</h1>

<table id="genotypes" class="display" data-source="<%= genotypes_url(format: "json") %>">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Marker</th>
      <th>LabID</th>
      <th>SubjectID</th>
      <th>Box</th>
      <th>Well</th>
      <th>Allele1</th>
      <th>Allele2</th>
      <th>Run date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
</tbody>
</table>

<br />
```

Please let me know if more code is needed...thanks!

Comment: 2 other files can be useful to see where is your problem : the view in which you render your datatable and the related js file, you can also add the rest of your GenotypesDatables.

Comment: Weird, your code seems ok to me, did your require your `genotypes` js in the `application.js` file?

Comment: Just tried that...no joy...think I'm going to have to take this a local Rails user group for some hands-in help...